# setAnimationListener working only after DrawerLayout open

Tags: android, animation

I have a MainActivity, which have DrawerLayout ,some fragments and layout.My class extends from FragmentActivity.

This Layout have margin -200 ( its do this layout out of bounds my activity).I want show this layout with animation.

The problem is: when i have click on button which start animation , animation dont run (when i debug mey code animation.setAnimationListener dont call), but when i swipe right my screen and calling drawerlayout to shows it, after this calling animation.setAnimationListener...whats i do wrong?

My code when i click on button which start animation:

`Animation slide = null;`

```
    slide = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
            R.anim.share_up);
    right_menu.startAnimation(slide);`

    slide.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

            right_menu.clearAnimation();

            FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            layoutParams.setMargins(0, topmargin, 0, 0);
            right_menu.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

        }

    });
```

My code to call drawer layout is simply:

`if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            } else {
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            }`

Comment: 1st slide.setAnimationListener & 2nd right_menu.startAnimation(slide); not the other way around

Comment: my layout name is right_menu.which i want to show with animation, or i am dont understand what do you mean

Comment: 1st you setAnimationListener. after you've done that you can startAnimation. if you do it the other way around the animation will start but the listener might not be set yet

Comment: ok,i fix this, but it not work untill i call drawerlayout

Comment: Solution of my issue was this code(i am forgot add setAnimation):
Animation slide = null;
  slide = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
    R.anim.share_up);

  slide.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {....};
right_menu.setAnimation(slide);
  right_menu.startAnimation(slide);